# In javascript, after i pass a non null object to a funtion it says the object is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object, functional-programming

i was trying to implement the A* algorithm and followed the wikipedia pseudo code to make this.

when i pass a predefined object pixel to the a funtion getG() it says that the object is null. I'm sorry if i am not pointing to a specific problem but i am not even sure how to really specify the problem by name. i have tried commenting out the code to increase readability.

git repository link of the whole project - https://github.com/NirobNabil/WhirlWind

(things are a little messy here because i didn't use github at first and i uploaded it just a little ago for posting the problem)

[ i'm actually making this to use a* to find path for my bot which is powered by arduino. thats why i'm using involt. ]

here goes the code,

```js
$(function() {
  // define the height, width and bot size in centemeter
  total_width = 200;
  total_height = 200;
  bot_size = 20;
  total_box = (total_height / bot_size) * (total_width / bot_size);
  box_in_x = total_width / bot_size;
  box_in_y = total_height / bot_size;
  //populating the pixels array
  populate(total_width / bot_size, total_height / bot_size, "UND");
  pathfind(pixels, pixels[13], pixels[pixels.length - 1]);
})

var pixels = []; //an array to hold all the objects(the grid) 

var obstacles = []; //array to hold the obstacles

function pixel(X, Y, obs) {
  this.X_co_ordinate = X;
  this.Y_co_ordinate = Y;
  this.state = obs; //availale states OPN, UND, OBS, DIS, NULL
  this.g = 0;
  this.h = 0;
  this.f = 0;
  this.last = null;
} //every block in the grid is a pixel

//01719372596

function populate(height, width, obs_val = "UND") {

  pixels[0] = new pixel(0, 10, obs_val);

  for (h = height, i = 0; h >= 0; h--) {
    for (w = 0; w < width; w++, i++) {
      var temp_obs = new pixel(w, h, obs_val);
      temp_obs.last = pixels[0];
      pixels[i] = temp_obs; //saving temp_pixel object to pixels array
    }
  }

} //populating the grid AKA pixels with pixel objects or blocks

// this funtion is where the problem shows up
function getG(current, start) {
  let g = 1;
  while (current != start && current.last != start && current) {
    current = current.last;
    g++;
  }

  return g;
} //get the g val(cost to come to this pixel from the start) of the current pixel


function getH(current, end) {
  let I = Math.abs(current.X_co_ordinate - end.X_co_ordinate) + Math.abs(current.Y_co_ordinate - end.Y_co_ordinate);
  return I;
} //get the h val(heuristic) of the current pixel

function getF(start, current, end) {
  let G = getG(current, start);
  let H = getH(current, end);
  return G + H;
} //get the f val(total) of the current pixel

function lowFinArray(arr, start, end) {
  // here arr is the grid/pixel
  let current_low = arr[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let getF1 = getF(start, current_low, end);
    let getF2 = getF(start, arr[i], end);
    if (getF1 < getF2) {
      current_low = arr[i];
    }
  }

  console.log("current low");
  console.log(current_low);

  return current_low;
}

function getneighbours(grid, current) {

  let neightbours = [];

  neightbours.push(grid[getIndex(current.X_co_ordinate - 1, current.Y_co_ordinate)]);
  neightbours.push(grid[getIndex(current.X_co_ordinate + 1, current.Y_co_ordinate)]);
  neightbours.push(grid[getIndex(current.X_co_ordinate, current.Y_co_ordinate - 1)]);
  neightbours.push(grid[getIndex(current.X_co_ordinate, current.Y_co_ordinate + 1)]);

  /*
  for(i=0; i<neightbours.length; i++){
      neightbours[i].last = current;
  }*/
  console.log("neightbours");
  console.log(neightbours);
  return neightbours;
} //get the neighbour pixels of the current pixel



//main algo
function pathfind(grid, start, end) {

  let closedSet = [];
  let openSet = [];
  openSet.push(start);
  let current = start;

  //trying to debug
  console.log("low F in arr");
  console.log(lowFinArray(grid, start, end));
  console.log(start);
  console.log(current);
  console.log(end);
  console.log(grid);


  let x = 0;
  while (openSet.length > 0) {

    //trying to debug
    console.log("executed " + (x++));
    console.log("openset");
    console.log(openSet);


    current = lowFinArray(grid, start, end); //assigning the pixel with lowest f val to current
    console.log("current");
    console.log(current);

    if (current == end) {

      console.log(getPath(current));
    }

    let neighbours = getneighbours(grid, current);
    for (let i = 0; i < neighbours.length; i++) {

      let neighbour = neighbours[i];

      if (closedSet.includes(neighbour)) {
        continue;
      }

      if (!openSet.includes(neighbours)) {
        openSet.push(neighbours);
      }

      //console.log(current);
      let getg = getG(current, start);
      let geth = getH(current, end);
      //console.log(getg);
      let tGscore = getg + geth; //here getH is being used as a distance funtion

      if (tGscore >= getg) {
        continue;
      }

      neighbour.last = current;
      neighbour.g = tGscore;
      neighbour.f = getF(neighbour);

    }
    if (x > 10) {
      return 0;
    }; //the loop was running forever so i tried this to stop the loop after 10 iterations
  }

}

function getPath(current) {

  let path = [current];
  while (current.last != null) {
    path.push(current.last);
  }

  return path;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and here is what the console says,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'last' of null
    at getG (app.js:226)
    at getF (app.js:241)
    at lowFinArray (app.js:249)
    at pathfind (app.js:292)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:92)
    at mightThrow (jquery-3.1.1.js:3570)
    at process (jquery-3.1.1.js:3638)
```

Comment: Please scale this down to a [mcve] representation of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing your checks in the wrong order:

```
while (current != start && current.last != start && current) {
```

There's no point in using `&& current` after you've already used `current.last`.

Perhaps changing the order would solve the problem. It will at least get rid of your current error:

```
while (current && current != start && current.last != start) {
```

Regarding the title of this question:

> In javascript, after i pass a non null object to a funtion it says the object is null

It may very well be non-null 100% of the time you pass it into the function, but you are repeatedly overwriting its parameter *within* the function, so all bets are off.

Comment: thanks. actually it was a typing mistake. it is lame of me to not notice that. sorry for wasting your time for such a lame mistake :(